# SQL Server : find percentage match of LIKE string

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, string

I'm trying to write a query to find the percentage match of a search string in a notes or `TEXT` column.

This is what I'm starting with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM NOTES 
WHERE UPPER(NARRATIVE) LIKE 'PAID CALLED RECEIVED'
```

Ultimately, what I want to do is:

1. Split the search string by spaces and search individually for all words in the string
2. Order the results descending based on percentage match

For example, in the above scenario, each word in the search string would constitute 33.333% of the total. A `NARRATIVE` with 3 matches (100%) should be at the top of the results, while a match containing 2 of the keywords (66.666%) would be lower, and a match containing 1 of the keywords (33.333%) would be even lower.

I then want to display the resulting percentage match for that row in a column, along with all the other columns from that table (*).

Hopefully, this makes sense and can be done. Any thoughts on how to proceed? This MUST all be done in SQL Server, and I would prefer not to write any CTEs.

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Very similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836884/is-it-possible-to-compare-rows-for-similar-data-in-sql-server/18837137#18837137  which I posted some UDF's I converted from VB code to do just that.

Comment: looks like you may want to find out about Full Text Search. It has `CONTAINS` and `CONTAINSTABLE` functions, you may have to use the `ISABOUT` condition together with the `weight()` option, like this `... WHERE CONTAINS(NARRATIVE, 'ISABOUT (PAID weight(0.333), CALLED weight(0.333), RECEIVED weight(0.333))')`, ... I've not even used this feature much.

Comment: An alternative...take a look at Levenshtein distance queires (google mssql Levenshtein)

Comment: @Twelfth I can't use `CONTAINS` OR `FREETEXT` because there is not a free text index on this field/table and I don't have authority to add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
DECLARE @VISIT VARCHAR(25) = '999232'
DECLARE @KEYWORD VARCHAR(100) = 'PAID,CALLED,RECEIVED'

DECLARE SPLIT_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(VALUE)) FROM Rpt_Split(@KEYWORD, ',')

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#NOTES_FF_SEARCH') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #NOTES_FF_SEARCH

SELECT   N.VISIT_NO
    ,N.CREATE_DATE
    ,N.CREATE_BY
    ,N.NARRATIVE
    ,0E8 AS PERCENTAGE
INTO #NOTES_FF_SEARCH
FROM NOTES_FF AS N
WHERE   N.VISIT_NO = @VISIT

DECLARE @KEYWORD_VALUE AS VARCHAR(255)

OPEN SPLIT_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM SPLIT_CURSOR INTO @KEYWORD_VALUE

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE #NOTES_FF_SEARCH
        SET PERCENTAGE = PERCENTAGE + ( 100 / @@CURSOR_ROWS )
    WHERE UPPER(NARRATIVE) LIKE '%' + UPPER(@KEYWORD_VALUE) + '%'

    FETCH NEXT FROM SPLIT_CURSOR INTO @KEYWORD_VALUE
END

CLOSE SPLIT_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE SPLIT_CURSOR


SELECT * FROM #NOTES_FF_SEARCH
WHERE PERCENTAGE > 0
ORDER BY PERCENTAGE, CREATE_DATE DESC
```

There may be a more efficient way to do this but every other road I started down ended in a dead-end.  Thanks for your help

Comment: this is awesome

Comment: Thanks for this! Helping out people nearly 5 years later!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a "percentage" match, you need to do two things:  calculate the number of words in the string and calculate the number of words you care about.  Before giving some guidance, I will say that full text search probably does everything you want and *much* more efficiently.

Assuming the search string has space delimited words, you can count the words with the expression:

```
(len(narrative) - len(replace(narrative, ' ', '') + 1) as NumWords
```

You can count the matching words with success replaces.  So, for keywords, it would be something like removing each key word, fixing the spaces, and counting the words.

The overall code is best represented with subqueries.  The resulting query is something like:

```
select n.*
from (select n.*,
             (len(narrative) - len(replace(narrative, ' ', '') + 1.0) as NumWords,
             ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(narrative + ' ', @keyword1 + ' ', ''),
                                         @keyword2 + ' ', ''), 
                                  @keyword3 + ' ', ''))) as NoKeywords
      from notes n
     ) n
order by 1 - (len(NoKeywords) - len(replace(NoKeywords, ' ', '') + 1.0)  / NumWords desc;
```

SQL Server -- as with many databases -- is not particularly good at parsing strings.  You can do that outside the query and assign the `@keyword` variables accordingly.