# SQLite search with typos

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have column (with removed ascent marks and tranformed to lowercase characters) in my table, where I am searching using LIKE. But I have problem when user make typo in input string.

For example I want this code returns Portugal.

```
SELECT * FROM Places
WHERE searchName like '%portgal%'
```

Comment: https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#soundex

Comment: you need to find a way by which you can find the matching percentage between the entered input and each searchName entry in your Places table, and if the percentage achieves a specific value then you accept it. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297055/sql-server-find-percentage-match-of-like-string

Comment: What kind of typos? Skipped letter (as example)? Two skipped letters? Inserted letter? Two inserted letters? Replaced letter (skip and insert different)? Swapped letters (single sequence mistake)? As phrased the question is too broad?

Comment: I think the percentage approuch from @AbdullahDibas is the right one.

Comment: @MatusMucka I would also suggest you to keep checking on the first letter in addition to the matching percentage.