# How to process SQL string char-by-char to build a match weight?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

The problem:  I need to display fields for user entry on a form, dynamic to some lookup criteria.

My current solution:  I've created a SQL table with some field entry criteria, based on a relatively simple matching criteria.  The match criteria basically is such that Lookup Value starts with Match Code, and the most precise match is found by doing a LEN comparison.

```sql
select 
      f.[IS_REQUIRED]
    , f.[MASK]
    , f.[MAX_LENGTH]
    , f.[MIN_LENGTH]
    , f.[RESOURCE_KEY]
    , f.[SEQUENCE]
from [dbo].[MY_RECORD] r with(nolock)
inner join [dbo].[ENTRY_FORMAT] f with(nolock)
    on  r.[LOOKUP_VALUE] like f.[MATCH_CODE]

-- Logic to filter by single, most-precise record match.
cross apply (
    select f1.[SEQUENCE]
    from [dbo].[ENTRY_FORMAT] f1 with(nolock)
    where f.[SEQUENCE] = f1.[SEQUENCE]
      and s.[MATCH_CODE] like f1.[MATCH_CODE]
    group by f1.[SEQUENCE]
    having len(f.[MATCH_CODE]) = max(len(f1.[MATCH_CODE]))
) tFilter

where r.[ID] = @RecordId
```

Current issues with this is that the most precise match has to be calculated each and every call, against each and every match.  Additionally, I'm only currently able to support the `%` in the `MATCH_CODE`.  (e.g., `'%'` is the default for all `LOOKUP_VALUE`, while an entry of `'12%'` would be the more precise match for a `LOOKUP_VALUE` of `'12345'`, and `MATCH_CODE` of `'12345'` should obviously me the most precise match.)  However, I would like to add support for `[4-7]`, etc. wildcards.  Going just off of LEN, this would definitely be wrong, because `'[4-7]'` adds a lot to the length, but, for example `'12345'` is still the desired match over `'123[4-7]'`

---

My desired update:  To add a `MATCH_WEIGHT` column to `ENTRY_FORMAT`, which I can update via a trigger on insert/update.  For my initial implementation, I'm just looking for something that can go through `MATCH_CODE`, character by character, increasing `MATCH_WEIGHT`, but treating `[..]` as just a single character when doing so.  Is there a good mechanism (UDF - either SQL or CLR? CURSOR?) for iterating through characters of a `varchar` field to calculate a value in this way?  Something like increasing `MATCH_WEIGHT` by two per non-wildcard, and perhaps by one on a wildcard; with details to be further thought out and worked out...

The goal being to use a query more like:

```sql
select 
      f.[IS_REQUIRED]
    , f.[MASK]
    , f.[MAX_LENGTH]
    , f.[MIN_LENGTH]
    , f.[RESOURCE_KEY]
    , f.[SEQUENCE]
from [dbo].[MY_RECORD] r with(nolock)

-- Logic to filter by single, most-precise record match.
cross apply (
    select top 1
          f1.[MATCH_CODE]
        , f1.[SEQUENCE]
    from [dbo].[ENTRY_FORMAT] f1 with(nolock)
    where r.[LOOKUP_VALUE] like f1.[MATCH_CODE]
    group by f1.[SEQUENCE]
    order by f1.[MATCH_WEIGHT] desc
) tFilter
inner join [dbo].[ENTRY_FORMAT] f with(nolock)
    on  f.[MATCH_CODE] = tFilter.[MATCH_CODE]
    and f.[SEQUENCE] = tFilter.[SEQUENCE]

where r.[ID] = @RecordId
```

---

Note: I realize this is a relatively fragile setup.  The `ENTRY_FORMAT` records are only entered by developers, who are aware of the restrictions, so for now assume that valid data is entered, and which does not cause match collisions.

---

With some help, I've come up with one implementation (answer below), but am still unsure as to my total design, so welcoming better answers or any criticism.

Comment: Can you provide more examples on how match weight is calculated ?

Comment: Have you looked into regex?

Comment: Side note. You should read this article before you continue splattering that NOLOCK hint everywhere. You claim you want precision but then you introduce NOLOCK and all precision is gone. You can and will get missing and/or duplicate rows. The upside is this happens completely randomly and is nearly impossible to reproduce on demand. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: What do you mean by "looking for something that can.."?   What kind of "something"?    Built-in SQL command?   Code that somebody else has already written?   a trained monkey?

Comment: @JoeC I had considered regex, though not totally sure on implementation.  Would that be via a CLR UDF?  My T-SQL knowledge is decent, but far from comprehensive.

Comment: See if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836884/is-it-possible-to-compare-rows-for-similar-data-in-sql-server

Comment: @Steve That did help come up with an implementation.  Going to post what I've come up with thus far.

Answer (score 0):

From [Steve's answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18837137/1223642), I've used much of the body to create a function to accomplish support for the `[..]` wildcard at the end of a match code.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalculateMatchWeight 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @MatchCode varchar(100)
)
RETURNS smallint
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result smallint = 0;

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    DECLARE @Pos int = 1, @N0 int = ascii('0'), @N9 int = ascii('9'), @AA int = ascii('A'), @AZ int = ascii('Z'), @Wild int = ascii('%'), @Range int = ascii('[');
    DECLARE @Asc int;
    DECLARE @WorkingString varchar(100) = upper(@MatchCode)

    WHILE @Pos <= LEN(@WorkingString)
    BEGIN
        SET @Asc = ascii(substring(@WorkingString, @Pos, 1));

        If ((@Asc between @N0 and @N9) or (@Asc between @AA and @AZ))
            SET @Result = @Result + 2;

        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- Check wildcard matching, update value according to match strength, and stop calculating further.
            -- TODO: In the future we may wish to have match codes with wildcards not just at the end; try to figure out a mechanism to calculating that case.
            IF (@Asc = @Range)
            BEGIN
                SET @Result = @Result + 2;
                SET @Pos = 100;
            END
            IF (@Asc = @Wild)
            BEGIN
                SET @Result = @Result + 1;
                SET @Pos = 100;
            END
        END

        SET @Pos = @Pos + 1
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result
END
```

I've checked that this can generate desired output for the current cases that I'm trying to cover:

```
SELECT [dbo].[CalculateMatchWeight] ('12345');      -- Most precise (10)
SELECT [dbo].[CalculateMatchWeight] ('123[4-5]');   -- Middle       (8)
SELECT [dbo].[CalculateMatchWeight] ('123%');       -- Least        (7)
```

Now I can call this function in a trigger on `INSERT`/`UPDATE` to update the `MATCH_WEIGHT`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_ENTRY_FORMAT_CalcMatchWeight
   ON  ENTRY_FORMAT
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    DECLARE @NewMatchWeight smallint = (select dbo.CalculateMatchWeight(inserted.MATCH_CODE) from inserted),
            @CurrentMatchWeight smallint = (select inserted.MATCH_WEIGHT from inserted);

    IF (@CurrentMatchWeight <> @NewMatchWeight)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE ENTRY_FORMAT
           SET MATCH_WEIGHT = @NewMatchWeight
          FROM inserted
         WHERE ENTRY_FORMAT.[MATCH_CODE] = inserted.[MATCH_CODE]
           AND ENTRY_FORMAT.[SEQUENCE] = inserted.[SEQUENCE]
    END
END
```